# three.js 3d model isn't showing up

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I tried everything I saw before but it didn't fix the problem. I can't display 3D models. Many people mentioned to me that it's a problem with the camera but can't seem to fix it. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My first Three.js app</title>
    <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="O:/FirstPublishedGame/FINAL-STEPS/levels/ForLevel3+/three.js-master/build/Three.js"></script>
    <script src="O:/FirstPublishedGame/FINAL-STEPS/levels/ForLevel3+/three.js-master/src/ob"></script>
    <script>

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, 
    window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    var element = document.getElementById("container");


    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    element.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load(
        'O:/FirstPublishedGame/FINAL-STEPS/levels/ForLevel3+/three.js-master/examples/obj/female02/female02.obj',
        function ( object ) {
            scene.add( object );
    });

    function render() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame( render );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }

    render();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an element with an id of container - try adding

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

At the beginning of your body.

Otherwise you can't set element to it.

Comment: and then i should add what exactly to the container?

Comment: Don't think you need to add anything inside the div - the renderer will handle that.